# Algorithm.sty not found

Tags: packages, texstudio, algorithms, algorithmic, miktex2.9

I have been using Miktek 2.9 and Texstudio as editor. There was a missing package of algorithms. I had downloaded it. Generated .sty file from .ins file. Copied the files to tex/latex. Refreshed FNDB. But still, it is not working saying algorithm.sty not found.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Best way to update MiKTeX 2.9: Open MiKTeX Console and install missing packages with packages (manager). MiKTeX Console knows best how to install missing packages.

Comment: the sty can be installed with the miktex console. But beside this: you probably put it in the wrong texmf tree. local files should never go into the main miktex tree (and if you do it anyway you have to update the fndb in admin mode).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, i updated the fndb in admin mode only.